# Sencha Touch Ext.js Codes in Html Page

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

How to use ext codes in html pages ?

Defined this :

```
    var Ext = Ext || {};
     var msg=new Ext.Msg();
        Ext.Msg.alert("Something","Something");
```

but Ext.Msg.alert doesnt work , throwing " undefined is not a function " error in console.

Answer (score 0):

work with this :

```
    Ext.onReady(function(){
      Ext.Msg.alert("rar","tatat");
    });
```